# Confusion regarding the definition of the Weyl Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

I've been studying algebraic structures recently; rings, fields, vector spaces and so on. I've recently just started learning what an algebra is, which, from what I can tell is a ring-like structure with scalar multiplication attached, so that the algebra $A$ forms a vector space with the $+$ and scalar multiplication operations.

The first example of an Algebra I encountered was the  First Weyl Algebra over the complex numbers, $A_1(\mathbb{C})$, but I'm confused regarding its definition. The definition I got said to look at the polynomial ring   $\mathbb{C}[x]$, and then regard this as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. They go on to define two linear operations $\delta$ and $x$, where $\delta$ is differentiation and $x$ is multiplication. Then $A_1 = {\{\sum_{i = 0}^{n} f_i(x) \delta^i : f_i(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x] }\}$.

$(1)$ How can we just regard the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a vector space? Aren't rings and vector spaces fundamentally different?

$(2)$ What exactly is an operator? Can we just think of them as operations like $+$ or multiplication?

$(3)$ I've seen expressions like $\delta^n \cdot x = n\delta^{n-1} + x\cdot\delta^n$ written, and I don't really understand what this means? Are we differentiating $x$ $n$ times or is this multiplication in the algebra?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I've never sat down to figure out this description either. Can you provide the source material you were reading?

Comment: *How can we just regard the polynomial ring ℂ[x] as a vector space? Aren't rings and vector spaces fundamentally different?* You talk about them as if they are forbidden to have anything in common, but of course they can. ℂ[x] is a set, and it can have a vector space structure and/or a ring structure. In fact, it does have a very obvious vector space structure: the one given by scalar multiplications on polynomials.  Algebras over fields are both rings and vector spaces over the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Of course we can just regard $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a vector space. A vector space is an abelian group equipped with the action of a field. A ring is an abelian group equipped with a multiplication, and an algebra is a ring equipped with the action of a field. In particular, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a vector space.

(2) An operator on a vector space $V$ is a linear transformation $T:V\to V$. The set of operators on $V$ is usually denoted by $\mathrm{End}(V)$. In particular, the map
$$
\delta: \mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{C}[x]
$$
given by $\delta(f)=f'$ is a linear operator. The map
$$
m_x:\mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{C}[x]
$$
given by $m_x(f)=xf$ is also a linear operator which, by abuse of notation, is referred to as '$x$'. In this context, $A_1\subset \mathrm{End}(V)$ is the algebra generated by $\delta$ and $x$.

(3) Multiplication in $\mathrm{End}(V)$ (and also $A_1$) is given by composition of functions. So, for example,
$$
(\delta\circ x)(f)=\delta(xf)=f + xf'=(1+x\circ\delta)(f)
$$
where the second equality follows by the product rule, and $1\in\mathrm{End}(V)$ is understood to be the identity transformation. The general statement can be proved by induction. Indeed, suppose the formula holds for the $(n-1)$-case. Then
\begin{align}
(\delta^n\circ x)(f)&=\delta((\delta^{n-1}\circ x)(f))\\
&=\delta((n-1)f^{(n-2)}+xf^{(n-1)})\\
&=(n-1)\delta(f^{(n-2)})+\delta(xf^{(n-1)})\\
&=(n-1)f^{(n-1)}+f^{(n-1)}+xf^{(n)}
\end{align}
therefore induction holds.

Comment: Ah, so that's how it works. I never got beyond the description of it as a quotient of $F\langle X, Y\rangle$

Comment: @rschwieb That's the version I'm used to as well. Since the representation of the Weyl algebra acting on $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is faithful, you may as well identify it with its image in $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}[x])$, which is all that's happening here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So the multiplication between $f$ and $\delta$ in the set $A_1 = {\{\sum_{i = 0}^{n} f_i(x) \delta^i : f_i(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x] }\}$ is a composition of functions?

Comment: yes, given $g(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, $(f(x)\delta^n)(g(x))=f(x)g^{(n)}(x)$. @theman

Comment: Ok, thank you. So the elements of $A_1$ are actually linear transformations?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. So how do we view $A_1$ as a ring? Is the $+$ the normal $+$ and the $x$ the composition of functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83705/discussion-between-david-hill-and-the-man).